# TortoiseSVN Folder-Shortcuts

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am writing some plug-ins for Eclipse and some of those plug-ins are collections from other plugins that are somehow spread over our repository. However, I don't want to write a readme file or explain to anyone what plugins he has to search from out repository. I just want that someone to check out one single folder that will contain all files that will be needed. I was thinking about **shortcuts**.

Imagine a structure like this:

```
https://mycompany/svn/Eclipse/plugins/ProjectX
https://mycompany/svn/Eclipse/plugins/ProjectY
https://mycompany/svn/Eclipse/plugins/RootZ/ProjectZa
https://mycompany/svn/Eclipse/plugins/RootZ/ProjectZb
...
```

But for whatever reason one only needs `ProjectX` and `ProjectZb` for a specific task. Therefore I'd like to have:

```
https://mycompany/svn/Eclipse/workspaces/PluginDevA/shortcutToProjectX
https://mycompany/svn/Eclipse/workspaces/PluginDevA/shortcutToProjectZb
```

such that I only have to checkout `PluginDevA` and SVN copies all referenced folders correctly to my local machine.

Is that somehow possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortcuts won't work, but there's a concept called `externals` that you can use.
Have a look at the documentation for the [svn:externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.externals.html) property. (or [tortoisesvn.net/../tsvn-dug-externals.html](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-externals.html))